# Upstart and process substitution

Tags: linux, bash, redirection, upstart

So I want to use the following in my `script` stanza:

```
forever -l >(tee $QW_LOG_DIR/webserver.log | logger -p user.info -t '[QW]') start webserver.js
```

However, that doesn't work for at least two reasons (I think):

1) There is a process created (the `>(...)` part) before my job, and so upstart will track that.

2) I am unsure why, but I get an error about the `(` in the console log. Does upstart run bash? Does it support process substitution?

What's my workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Upstart runs the script in `/bin/sh`. Process substitution is bash specific.

Read the upstart cookbook for more information:

- [Develop Scripts Using `/bin/sh`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#develop-scripts-using-bin-sh)
- [Changing the Default Shell](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#changing-the-default-shell)

Comment: So would it be fair to say that I need to use `mkfifo` in my `pre-start` stanza so that I can write to the fifo in my start script, thus avoid both the bash syntax and that fact that I have another process? If so, I would also need to run `(tee fifo | logger ...)` in the background in my pre-start. How would I end it in `pre-stop`?

Comment: I am not skilled enough in upstart to be able to answer that question. I suggest you ask that question here on superuser or on askubuntu.